# iOS can't play uploaded audio: JS MediaRecorder -> Blob -> Django Server -> AWS s3 -> JS decodeAudioData --> "EncodingError: Decoding Failed"

Tags: django, amazon-s3, web-audio-api, audio-recording, web-mediarecorder

**Answer:** shouldn't set content/mime type browser side with JS, should use native browser mimeType then convert server side (I used PyDub).

**Question:**
I am using Javascript MediaRecorder, Django, AWS s3 and Javascript Web Audio API to record audio files for users to share voice notes with one another. I've seen disbursed answers online about how to record and upload audio data and the issues with Safari/iOS but thought this could be a thread to bring it together and confront some of these issues.

Javascript:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
    var blob = new Blob(
        chunks,
        {
            type:"audio/mp3",
        }
    );
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('recording', blob)
    var resp = await fetch(url, { // Your POST endpoint
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
        },
        body: formdata,
    })
}
```

Django:

```
for k,file in request.FILES.items():
    sub_path = "recordings/audio.mp3"
    meta_data = {"ContentType":"audio/mp3"}
    s3.upload_fileobj(file, S3_BUCKET_NAME, sub_path,ExtraArgs=meta_data)
    ###then some code to save the s3 URL to my database for future retrieval
```

Javascript:

```
var audio_context = new AudioContext();

document.addEventListener("#play-audio","click", function(e) {
    var url = "https://docplat-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/recordings/audio.mp3"
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function () {
        audio_context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buffer) {
            playSound(buffer)
        });
    }
    request.send();
})
```

Results in:
"EncodingError: Decoding Failed"

Note however that using the w3 schools demo mp3 url does play the recording:
https://docplat-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/recordings/t-rex-roar.mp3

Specs:
PC (used to upload recoding): Windows 11, Chrome Version 98.0.4758.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Django: Version: 3.1.7
Mobile (used to play recording): iPhone X, iOS (Version 14.7.1)
Problematic url:  https://docplat-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/recordings/audio.mp3
Working url: https://docplat-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/recordings/t-rex-roar.mp3

(This is my first post so please forgive me if I haven't asked this question in the ideal way :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload the recorded `Blob` you set the type to `'audio/mp3'`. But unless you use a custom library which patches the `MediaRecorder` the `mimeType` of the recording will be whatever the browser likes best.

As of now it's `'audio/opus'` in Firefox and `'audio/webm'` in Chrome.

If you define your `Blob` like this it should work.

```
var blob = new Blob(
    chunks,
    {
        type: mediaRecorder.mimeType
    }
);
```

You would also have to change your server side code to not use `'audio/mp3'` anymore.

Comment: So I've changed the MediaRecorder javascript to that, but then the issue becomes converting the webm audio file to a file format which can be played on an iPhone. I took the webm output from recording Chrome, saved it locally then converted it to mp3 using this tool:
https://convertio.co/download/1eaece5509f6cbdaa6d61c9162c94b178c95bb/
The outcome is an mp3 which again can be played anywhere but not on iPhone.

Comment: Update: Thank you so much for this, your insight was the key thing I needed. The conclusion is that I used the browser's native mimeType then did conversion server side with PyDub:
`AudioSegment.from_file(file,format="webm")`
`file = io.BytesIO()`
`audio.export(file, format="mp3", bitrate="320k")`
Effectively I converted the file object (from django, see above).

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you found a solution. Just in case if re-encoding a lossy format into another lossy format is an issue for you, you could try using a library like [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder). I once created it to record WAV files which can be decoded again by every browser. The downside is of course the larger file size.